# Unable to add reference to Bing Maps?

Tags: c#, silverlight, api, bing-maps

I was trying to create an app using Bing Map. in which i need to add two reference libraries

```
Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Common.dll
Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.dll
```

I followed the tutorial from : http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/article.php/c18305__1/Working-with-Bing-Maps-in-Silverlight-and-Windows-Phone-7-Applications.htm

But when i installed BingMapAppSDK from Bing Maps it didn't have these api. 
It does have libraries

```
    Microsoft.Maps.Core;
    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;
    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Types;
    Microsoft.Maps.Plugins;
```

But not the above ones.. Due to this i am not able to use Bing Maps.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and creating Silverlight app and Silverlight 5 is installed.

Please suggest.

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Windows Phone 7.5 includes the control in the SDK directly, without having to jump through any additional hoops (and the article is referring to Windows Phone).

Comment: @unitPower : The 4 shown below. But missing above two (necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different Bing Maps SDKs for different platforms although, confusingly, they do share rather similar namespaces. It's really unclear from your post which platform you're trying to target...

- To develop a Silverlight Bing Maps application, you need the Bing Maps Silverlight control SDK, available from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2949
- To develop a Windows Phone 7 Bing Maps application, you need the Windows Phone 7 SDK, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570
- To develop a "Bing Maps App" (note the quotation marks), which is a special kind of Bing Maps application that is hosted by Microsoft on the bing.com/maps site, you need the Bing Maps App SDK: http://connect.microsoft.com/bingmapapps

Note that there are also dedicated Bing Maps SDKs for iOS, Android, and WPF development, as well as the traditional AJAX control.

Comment: He specified he was using Silverlight 5. I think CracLock has the correct SDK already if he has reference to those four namespaces.

Comment: The OP said they were "creating Silverlight app", but posted a link to a tutorial on Windows Phone 7, and stated that they'd downloaded the BingMapsAppSDK... so that's three different APIs, as I've documented above.

Comment: Most of the information (tags, dlls, namespaces, etc.) that was provided pointed towards Silverlight (web), however, I seem to have assumed incorrectly based on their answer selection.

Answer (score 2):

You have To add a Service Reference.

1 . Right click on "reference" and then Add Service Reference.
then copy one of the four links from here which you want to use.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966738.aspx

1. Click on go .
2. Name it according to you .
3. Now try to add namespaces 
   like

using ProjectName.GeocodeService;

using ProjectName.ImageryService;

Hope This helps.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the dll's can be different from the namespaces they provide. If I understand your question correctly, you already have access to everything you need. The four libraries are what you need to make your apps, while the dll files are what you are already using to get access to those namespaces.

In the example link you listed, he shows how make a reference to the map control namespace by doing the following:

```
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl; assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl"
```

In this case, the assembly (dll file) and the namespace are the same, but they don't have to be and thats why they are specified separately.

From here, just add the map control.

```
<m:Map CredentialsProvider="Your_Credentials" />
```